# itextsharp Save Working with internet explorer and giving download option but not giving download option with google chrome and not saving file

Tags: google-chrome, itext

The code is working with internet explorer and giving required result but not working with google Chrome

```
 string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + TitlePdf;
 Response.ClearContent();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

 HTMLWorker htmlworker = new HTMLWorker(document);
 htmlworker.Parse(new StringReader(done));
 document.Close();
 Response.Write(document);
 Response.End();
```

Comment: Your iTextSharp code is correct (nothing to fix: it works perfectly in most browsers), but you're experiencing a problem with Google Chrome, so I added the Google-Chrome tag.

Comment: kindly some one suggest solution for this problem.

Comment: @Bruno *Your iTextSharp code is correct* - with `HTMLWorker` use and `Response.Write(document);`?

Comment: I've overlooked that one a bunch of times, too. `Response.Write(document);` should be completely removed as it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: To the OP, in Google Chrome do you even see the PDF or does it not render at all?

Comment: I overlooked that. I believed the OP when he wrote that it worked in other browsers.